# strange bug with ASP.NET inline expression

Tags: asp.net

If I enter the following mark-up in my aspx page, it builds with no errors:

```
<%if(_Competition == null && IsCompetitionPage)
         {%>
```

But!

```
<%else if(_Competition == null && IsCompetitionPage)
         {%>
```

gives the following error:

CS1525: Invalid expression term 'else'

Comment: It's difficult to tell without more context, but have you confirmed that you have a previous if statement to match the else, and that it is bracketed correctly? CS1525 is a compiler error and not specific to ASP.NET.

Comment: Yes, everything else is ok.

Comment: Could you include the surrounding code in your original question please, i.e. the complete if/else expression.

Comment: Well, it's work code, so can't breach privacy etc, but the essential code is here:  <%if(_Competition == null && IsCompetitionPage)
         {%>

<%}%>
<%else if(!IsCompetitionPage){%>
<%}%>

Comment: I tried to put the code in code blocks but the {} link wasn't there to click on like it was initially !!

Answer (score 1):

Remove any page content you've placed between the closing brace of the `if` statement and the start of the `else`.

For example, this will fail:

```
<%
  if (_Competition == null && IsCompetitionPage) {
%>
    <h2>Some content</h2>
<%}%>

INVALID CONTENT HERE

<%
  else if (!IsCompetitionPage) {
%>
    <h2>Some different content here</h2>
<%}%>
```

Removing 'INVALID CONTENT HERE' should fix the issue.